# How do I add to an array if each array element has multiple features?

Tags: html, arrays, arraylist

In HTML, how do I add an item to an array if each element in an array list has multiple parts?

I'm creating a custom map for Google Maps, and I'm using a form to input a new coordinate into the array.  The array is a list of coordinate positions, with the icon associated with them.  I have a form in the body that uses a submit button to call an addLocation function I put in the header, which updates the coordinates array and the map as well.  Is this code right so far, as far as the array manipulation goes?  Any ideas or tips?  This is what mine basically looks like, and the coordinates are just examples.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Custom Markers</title>
    <script>
        var features = 
            [
              {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91721, 151.22630),
                type: 'starter'
              },
              {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91539, 151.22820),
                type: 'unown'
              }
            ];
        function addLocation(coordinates)
        {
            features.push(***this is the part I'm not sure about***);
        }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="newlocation">
        <p> Add a new location:</br>
            <form action=addLocation(coordinates)>
                Coordinates:  <input type="text" name="coordinates">  <input type="submit">
            </form> 
        </br>
        </br>
        </p>

    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91722, 151.23064),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        var iconBase = 'C:\Users\JM\Desktop\UnownMap\Icons\';
        var icons = {
          starter: {
            icon: iconBase + 'starting.png'
          },
          unown: {
            icon: iconBase + 'unownLoc.png'
          }
        };

        // Create markers.
        features.forEach(function(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
          });
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=___________&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this okay?

Comment: you'll need to figure out how to get from your coordinates element to a "feature" object. You can get text from the element, but you'll have to parse that into numbers and construct a LatLng.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your feature objects, you basically need 3 things to construct one:

- latitude
- longitude
- type

The simplest approach would therefore be to have 3 inputs in your form. If you have just one input you'll need to parse the text and figure out what part is latitude, what part is longitude, etc. Why go through that hassle? So let's try your form like this:

(EDIT: I've changed this to use more standard onsubmit behavior. Using action cannot access "this" and is not considered standard).

```
   <form onsubmit="addLocation(this); return false">
        Latitude:  <input type="text" name="latitude">  <br>
        Longitude:  <input type="text" name="longitude"><br>  
        Type:  <input type="text" name="featuretype">  <br>
        <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

Of course, you are free to try and do the parsing of one field, but from your question I think that will be a challenge for you.

To handle that in your javascript (let's be clear, HTML doesn't have arrays, javascript does), you now are being passed a form object, from which you can access all of the elements.

To get the value of each element, you would do something like this:

```
form.elements["elementname"].value
```

where "form" is the name of the form. So you javascript function starts out:

```
function addLocation(myform)
{
    var lat = myform.elements["latitude"].value;
    var lng = myform.elements["longitude"].value;
    var featuretype = myform.elements["featuretype"].value;
    ...
```

This step may be unnecessary, depending on if the google api does it automatically for you, but you can convert the strings into floats like this:

```
   lat = parseFloat(lat);
   lng = parseFloat(lng);
```

Once you have those 3 values, you can create a new feature object, just like the original ones in the array:

```
    var feature = {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
          type: featuretype
    };
```

and add it to the array

```
    features.push(feature);
```

Comment: If I create a new feature object, would that replace my old one?